# Calculate distance for multiple locations google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Assume I have 3 locations namely Kallang(A), Paya Lebar(B) and Bedok(C). I try to do a A->B + B->C but the distance always return me A->C. Why is this so ??

kallang to paya lebar(A-B) -> 2.5914199062350742 km

paya lebar to bedok(B-C) -> 4.4403012109180775 km

total (A-B-C) -> 7.03 km

kallang to bedok (A-C) -> 6.88 km

below are my codes:

```
var R = 6371; 
    var dLat = toRad(location3.lat()-location2.lat()) + toRad(location2.lat()-location1.lat());
    var dLon = toRad(location3.lng()-location2.lng()) + toRad(location2.lng()-location1.lng());

    var dLat1 = toRad(location1.lat());
    var dLat2 = toRad(location2.lat());

    var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
            Math.cos(dLat1) * Math.cos(dLat1) * 
            Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2); 
    var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)); 
    var d = R * c;

    document.getElementById("distance_direct").innerHTML = "<br/><br/><br/>The distance between the five points (in a straight line) is: "+d +" km.";
}

function toRad(deg) 
{
    return deg * Math.PI/180;
}
```

Is it something wrong with my adding and subtracting calculation statement ??? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, the problem is with adding and substracting the same thing. Since `toRad()` is just a multiplication, it's associative respective to + and - and therefore

```
var dLat = toRad(location3.lat()-location2.lat())
         + toRad(location2.lat()-location1.lat());
```

is exactly the same as

```
var dLat = toRad(location3.lat()-location1.lat());
```

so you end up calculating the straight distance between the first and last point.

If you are using the Google Maps JavaScript API V3, you can just load the [Geometry Library](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry.html) and do this:

```
var indirect_distance = 
    google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(location1, location2)
  + google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(location2, location3);
```

Comment: Thanks your help was excellent.. Manage to did it... Many thanks :D

Answer (score 3):

You can just use the built in computeDistanceBetween method from the [geometry library](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry.html)